# Return two values in Robot Framework

Tags: function, variables, return, automated-tests, robotframework

Is there a possibility to return two variables in Robot Framework?

```
${result1}, ${result2}=    MyKeyword
```

doesn't work.

Comment: There is a great user guide you should read: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#user-keyword-return-values

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, just place the variables in separate cells, both when assigning and when returning the values.

For example:

```
*** Test Case ***
Example
    ${value1}    ${value2}    return two values
    Should be equal    ${value1}    this is value 1
    Should be equal    ${value2}    this is value 2


*** Keywords ***
Return two values
    ${v1}=      set variable    this is value 1
    ${v2}=      set variable    this is value 2

    [Return]    ${v1}    ${v2}
```

Answer (score 6):

Remove the ,

```
${result1}    ${result2}    =    MyKeyword
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. '${result1} ${result2}=' --> keyword not found

Comment: Guessing this was an issue with separation or you weren't actually returning two values from the keyword

Comment: And also an issue with the equals sign.

Comment: yes this is the separation issue, it's because you have the equals sign on the variable.  If it were separated appropriately it should work fine unless I'm mistaken

Comment: I realize it is a year since this post, but the answer here is mildly syntactically incorrect.  There cannot be more than 1 space between the '=' and the variable to its left (zero spaces are fine as well).  Any more spaces results in Robot treating the equal sign as a distinct keyword (which will fail).  Unfortunately, since SO thinks the edit is too trivial, I can't remove those spaces.

Comment: @logicalscope I'm afraid I disagree, I used the above method many times without it failing.  My previous workplace used 4spaces as separation and it worked without issue

Answer (score 5):

```
${result1}    ${result2} =    MyKeyword
```

worked for me.

```
${result1}    ${result2}    =    MyKeyword
```

gave me:

```
No keyword with name '=' found.
```

In case it matters, I'm using spaces only, no tabs.